# How do I make cartographic maps with relief and color?

Tags: 3d-view, height-map, bump

I am trying to make a cartographic map like this, I have the *qgis* software, *base layers*, and *Dem* available. What will be the workflow which I need to proceed to make maps like this?

[image]

Comment: Hello, the person shared their personal workflow in the link you provided : Use a height map to drive the displacement of a mesh, then texture it and add post-processing effects. Please share your attempts and where you are stuck, otherwise the question is too broad to even attempt to answer it fully

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this?r=SearchResults

Comment: For a beginner like me it would be really difficult to start without any pathway. If there is any respective discussions or tutorials available kindly share it with me.

Comment: Let me try the same and will get back to u.